# Inserts to .mdb slow over network from Win 2016 Server, Fast from Win 2003

Tags: performance, ms-access, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2016

I'm Moving a legacy win app from a Win2003Server to a Win2016Server. A .Net 2.0 app that processes images then writes the output to an empty msAccess .mdb file.

The Application processes the images quickly as it did on Win 2003.

Issue is when it opens the msAccess file over the network and loops inserting 1 row @ time it's running slowly from the Win 2016 Server but fast from the Win 2003 Server. Same Code, Same target Network server.

We've turned off Firewalls and everything we can think.

I've built a Win 2016 Server in VirtualBox with Visual Studio and have reproduced the problem however, oddly, the first time I ran the application it wrote the inserts to the .mdb quickly. Every other time it's slow. Reboot etc nothing will get it to run fast again. Is something cached?

Any suggestions?

- Win 2003 3500 Images writes .mdb in 30 seconds or less
- Win 2016 3500 Images writes .mdb in 30 minutes!

Comment: My workaround is to write the .mdb locally then copy the end result over the network to it's 'resting place'. That will run quickly. Trying to find cause of original problem.

Comment: It's a 32bit app running on a 64 bit server.